# How to avoid duplicating a function call in this JPA/JPQL query?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following JPA query that truncates dates to a full hour and counts them:

```
SELECT a.alertconfiguration.id.id,
       date_trunc('hour', a.date) AS fromDate,
       count(*)                   AS count
FROM   alert a
GROUP  BY a.alertconfiguration.id.id,
          a.alertlevel,
          date_trunc('hour', a.date)
```

I'm running this in a Spring Boot application using Hibernate. It works fine. But I don't want to duplicate the function call to `date_trunc`.
I have tried referring to fromDate in the GROUP BY clause but then I get an exception `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "fromdate" does not exist`

http://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9301 also states it is not possible to refer to aliases in the group by clause.

How could I rewrite my query without the duplicate function call?

Comment: Why do you think that `date_trunc` appearing in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses necessarily means that the database is actually calling it twice?  The only way to avoid this would be to generate `fromDate` in a subquery.  But, that would have serious performance implications.  I am happy with your current version.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
Perhaps not necessarily, I don't know if it could optimize that away, I don't know enough about it. I don't like duplicating calls but if this sounds reasonable to others then I don't mind in particular.

Comment: When you invoke `GROUP BY`, you put the database into `GROUP BY` mode.  It needs to keep the terms used in the `GROUP BY` clause around as it executes the query.  So, my point is that there might actual be just _one_ call to `date_trunc` which is needed here.

Comment: Can you give a try using 2 instead of date_trunc('hour', a.date) in group by clause, as fromdate is 2nd column?

Comment: @RamachandraReddy yes that actually works too! You should turn this into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek I just did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give a try using 2 instead of date_trunc('hour', a.date) in group by clause, as fromdate is 2nd column

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does not work with alias in group by or any aggregate functions. And as you will see in your sql query generated, the alias is different than that you have assigned.

Comment: So what should I do then?

Comment: you need to have to duplicate your date_trunc function. There is jira defects regarding this . search on google.